# why my scanner can only take two numbers? Java

Tags: java, input

I am trying to use a Scanner object to read keyboard input (double type numbers). The program compiles, but it can only take two numbers. Below is my code, please help me find the reason. Thank you!

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<String>();
        double number = 0;

        System.out.println("Type in the polynomials in increasing powers:");

        while (!keyboard.nextLine().isEmpty())
        {           
//          number = keyboard.nextDouble();
            try {
                     number = keyboard.nextDouble();
            } catch(Exception e)              // throw exception if the user input is not of double type
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
            }


            container.add("-" + number);

        }
```

Comment: Because you read too much input, see your `while` loop condition. Use `hasNextDouble()` to look ahead.

Comment: thanks sotirios. When I use keyboard.haxNextDouble(), the while loop never stops even with a blank line input. The blank line is supposed to stop it.

Answer (score 2):

The method call `nextLine()` in

```
while (!keyboard.nextLine().isEmpty())
```

will consume the first `double` value you enter. This

```
number = keyboard.nextDouble();
```

will then consume the second one.

When the loop iterates again, `keyboard.nextLine()` will consume the trailing end of line characters which it will `trim()`. `isEmpty()` will therefore return `true`.

The solution if you want to enter a number, press enter, and keep entering numbers is to read the line as a `String` and use `Double.parseDouble(String)` to get a `double` value.

Otherwise, you can also use

```
while (keyboard.hasNextDouble()) {
    number = keyboard.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(number);
    ...
}
```

And enter your numbers on a single line separated by spaces

```
22.0 45.6 123.123123 -61.31 -
```

Use a random non-numerical character at the end to tell it input is done. The above prints

```
22.0
45.6
123.123123
-61.31
```

and stops.